# Can't see logical Windows NTFS partition in OS X

Tags: macos, windows, partition

I have already asked this question over here

https://superuser.com/questions/323414/cant-see-logical-windows-ntfs-partition-in-os-x

and I got one answer thats satisfying but risky to attempt such action, so anyone else can up with less risky alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I vote for installing NTFS-3G via macports and it is the best way IMHO. Check this well-written and detailed description http://fernandoff.posterous.com/ntfs-write-support-on-osx-lion-with-ntfs-3g-f

Answer (score 1):

Mac OS X does not natively support RW access to NTFS partitions.

You'll need a combination of MacFUSE:

http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/

and Amit Singh's NTFS RW driver:

http://macntfs-3g.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 1):

MacFuse is pretty much abandonware, and hasn't been updated since 2009. There is a new project called OSXFuse that is picking up where MacFuse left off and is compatible with Lion:

http://osxfuse.github.com/

Also, as of 10/25/2011, the easy download location for the open source NTFS-3G

http://macntfs-3g.blogspot.com/2010/10/ntfs-3g-for-mac-os-x-2010102.html